# Moment js convert milliseconds into date and time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have current time in milliseconds as - 1454521239279

How do I convert it to 03 FEB 2016 and time as 11:10 PM ?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/#format-dates

Answer (score 186, accepted):

**Moment parser**

```
moment(1454521239279).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a") //parse integer
moment("1454521239279", "x").format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a") //parse string
```

**Moment unix method**

```
moment.unix(1454521239279/1000).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a")
```

Comment: Dude, you just saved me. Have been looking for answer from last 2 hours, nothing worked except this :)

Comment: in my response_date_string I am getting 616090400000 and i need to show date with time which should be in this case 2021-03-18 18:00:00 , any idea ?

Comment: In the current version of moment these methods throw a deprecation warning.

Comment: It seems doing a `parseInt("123123123312")` suppresses the warning.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 1o digit 1591074937 then you can convert like this.

```
moment(1591074937*1000).format("DD MMM YYYY")

OR

new Date(1591074937 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this
`moment(1662969163000).format("DD/MM/YYYY")`