# Using moment.js how do I give a specific format for a duration

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given a duration of a number of seconds coming from an API as `duration_seconds = 86485`.

(1 day, 0 hours, 1 minute, 1 second)

I was going to use moment.js to convert this into formatted duration as follows:

```
 1. {d} {hh}:{mm}:{ss} (1d 00:01:01)
 2. {d}d {hh}h m{mm} s{ss} (1d 04h 30m 23s)
```

I would also like to ensure the following:

- Days are trimmed if days is 0 (`00:01:01` - for 1 minute 1 second)
- hh:mm:ss are never trimmed, 1 second shows as `00:00:01`.

I can create the duration like this:

```
moment.duration(duration_seconds, 'seconds')
```

The humanize function is not suitable as it approximates. 
I can also write my own with:

```
duration.get('d')
duration.get('h')
duration.get('m')
duration.get('s')
```

I can't seem to find a built in function but I assume this would be an obvious one? Is there something I am missing, otherwise I can PR one into moment library.

This seems to imply that the function still does not exist: 
[Using moment.js, How can I simplify a duration to its most simplified form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079230/using-moment-js-how-can-i-simplify-a-duration-to-its-most-simplified-form)

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: There are plugins to MomentJS. One seems to be what you're asking for: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/

Comment: https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Thanks @MikeMcCaughan. I also saw that this one is posted quite regularly in the GitHub issues complaining about this problem.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that plugin still doesn't really solve the full problem. 

If you have one second, using format ('hh:mm:ss'), it still shows the duration as `01` and not `00:00:01`

Comment: Well, then I guess the answer to your question is "There is no built-in function. You should consider submitting a PR either to moment.js or the plugin."

Comment: Yep, busy formulating my findings and will post them here. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - note that this already exists in the plugin.  I added to my answer below.

Comment: @MattJohnson Not sure why you're pinging me. I didn't say it didn't exist in the plugin; the OP said they tried it and it didn't work for them. I just said that there is no built-in function in MomentJS. Obviously if they tried to submit a PR for existing functionality to the plugin, they'd find that out pretty quick :).

Comment: Just trying to be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plugin can assist you with this.

```js
// your input
var duration_seconds = 86485;

// create a moment-duration object
var duration = moment.duration(duration_seconds, 'seconds');

// format the object with a string
var formatted = duration.format('h[h] m[m] s[s]');

// displaying the output here
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = formatted;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
<div id="output" />
```

Note that by default it will omit units that are not relevant, so if your input is 3, it's just going to say `"3s"`, not `"0h 0m 3s"`.

If you want to change this behavior, set `trim:false`, [per the documentation](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#trim).  For example, to get the format you mentioned in comments, use:

```
.format('hh:mm:ss', { trim: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this?

`moment(duration).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm: a")`

Though you might have to convert your seconds to milliseconds. This can be done by saying `duration * 1000`.

Found from this answer: [Moment js convert milliseconds into date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184003/moment-js-convert-milliseconds-into-date-and-time)

Comment: `formation` isn't a function, I think you meant `format`.  But if you're going to do this, you'll need to use `moment.utc(duration)` (or `moment.unix(duration)` if you don't want to * 1000).

Comment: You will also have problems if you have more than 31 days to represent.  Ultimately, formatting a date/time is different than formatting a duration.

Comment: @MattJohnson ah, thanks for the spell check! Interesting, I am not a pro at moment.js, so I will leave it up to people who are more capable of answering this question.

Comment: This answer isn't suitable. I need to deal with durations and not points in time.