# momentjs format duration to [hh:mm:ss] with hh larger than 24hours

Tags: momentjs

How can I use momentjs to format a number in seconds like

```
moment(172800).format('hh[h] mm[min]')
```

to some like

```
'48h 00min'
```

in essential I want to count timer pass in hh:mm:ss with hours going way beyond 24.

Comment: For things like this, you should really be using [`moment.duration()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/). You are working with durations, not specific times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using moment.js how do I give a specific format for a duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171723/using-moment-js-how-do-i-give-a-specific-format-for-a-duration)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in.

You can create a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) from your seconds and then use `format` method from [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) to print duration according your needs.

Here a example:

```js
// Create moment duration
var dur = moment.duration(172800, 's');
// Format duration according your needs
console.log( dur.format('hh[h] mm[min]') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A native solution will be something like:

```
getTimeBySeconds = (seconds) => {
    const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60);
    const secondsLeft = seconds % 3600 % 60;

    return `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${secondsLeft.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
}
```